# Should I upload my gpt encrypted passwords to github?

Tags: github, password-store

I am currently using Pass as my password manager and I want to use it on my phone too. So I download [Android Password Storage](https://github.com/zeapo/Android-Password-Store) on my phone because it was listed as an android app for Pass at home page of pass. But for initializing it I need a git repository. Is there a problem to pushing it to a secret Github repository then syncing at there?

Comment: Depends on how much you trust Microsoft and Github.  Many companies trust secret data in private repositories that is far more valuable than your password though.  Personally I would be more skeptical about the android app than github.

Comment: github also supports repo-specific keys so no need to give permission to anything else in your github account. with your global all-permissions key that would be another worry, github accounts do get hacked ...

Comment: You can trust github private repos as much as you trust any cloud file service.

Comment: Never place GPG private data on anything that is not under your complete, direct control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your passwords are GPG-encrypted. Breaking the GPG encryption is (let's say) impossible. So, you shouldn't fear about the security of your encrypted file, as long as you take care of your private key. Keep in mind that if someday your private key becomes compromised, and you keep the passwords file in a public repository, anyone would be able to decrypt it. Also, the main issue is the Android app which doesn't seem to be very popular and trusted. It'd have access to both your passwords file and your GPG private key. It has to, to give you your passwords. If you're paranoid, you'd need to read every single part of the Android app's source code to see if you find anything suspicious. Then you may compile it yourself and run your own version (which you're 100% sure is compiled from the same source code).